# "Raid 0 SAS" versus "2nd generation SSD"

Tags: ssd, raid, sas

i was planning to buy a SAS system made of two 15k RPM disks in Raid 0 configuration to give a boost to my s.o. and my apps... but after i saw [that article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001304.html) on Coding Horror, i've started to thinking if a new 2nd generation SSD could do the same job, or even better...
Does anybody have any information to help me decide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With RAID 0 you have that chance of failure and losing everything, and you still get read lag. With an SSD, you have a lesser chance of losing everything, and **no read lag at all**. That means when you open something it will begin to load almost instantly, unlike traditional HDDs where the read head has to be physically moved into position.

However, with your SSD you'll also need another HDD (If you're considering raid 0 you're probably not the sort of guy who can get along with 128GB of storage space ;)), but that carries it's own advantages. I think the Small/Fast SSD and Big/Slow HDD method is about the best you can get for reasonable prices right now.

edit: John makes a good point, SSDs are silent and require much less power, as well as giving off less heat.

Comment: yeah i think you are right... a new SSD drive fits better to my needs (and is more cool :P)

Comment: That's an additional point, running an SSD has that "geek cred" feel right now that'll give you a warm fuzzy feeling every time you boot up your PC. Good luck finding a hdd to do that :P

Comment: Agreed.  Also, a couple of 15k drives will add a significant amount of heat/noise/power consumption.